# Service location - check the project for implementation

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, service-locator

When the project uses the service locator the implementation classes registers in the locator. And then at run-time in certain places locator is asked to resolve certain service like this (A lot of these services are singletons):

```
LSvc := Locator.Resolve<ISomeService>;
```

The bad thing is that it's kind of anti-pattern. But assuming this happens as it is, is there a way to check that there is a unit which implements the ISomeService by registering the class in the locator like this?

```
Locator.Register<ISomeService>(TSomeService);
```

1. Parsing the source files;
2. Having the special units called "*.Dependencies.pas" where all the implementation units are listed.

What else can be done in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to find this using the RTTI informations. So the code below will work only for recent versions of Delphi.

```
var
  LIntf, LClass: TRttiType;
  LImpl: TRttiInterfaceType;
  LCtx: TRttiContext;
  LFound: Boolean;
begin
  LCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
  for LIntf in LCtx.GetTypes do
    if LIntf.TypeKind = tkInterface then
      begin
        LFound := False;
        for LClass in LCtx.GetTypes do
          begin
            if LClass.TypeKind = tkClass then
              for LImpl in TRttiInstanceType(LClass).GetImplementedInterfaces do
                if LImpl.QualifiedName = LIntf.QualifiedName then
                  begin
                    LFound := True;
                    Break;
                  end;

            if LFound then
              Break;
          end;

        if not LFound then
          Writeln(LIntf.QualifiedName, ' is not implemented by any class.');
      end;
end;
```

You can filter the interfaces and types by the QualifiedName. The name contains the full unit name as a prefix to the type.

So even without applying the filter it is possible to save the output of this to the text file and after filtering out unneeded (not required interfaces) you will be able to find the interfaces which are compiled in the project, but there is no classes which implements them.

This exactly is the case when the services are reused between projects and requested via service locator.